# Why do I keep getting 415 WatsonException: Error: unsupported media type in Python?

Tags: python, json, get, httprequest, ibm-watson

I am trying to use Watson api for sentiment analysis.
The code is quite simple.
But why do I keep getting this error?????

```
WatsonException: Error: unsupported media type, Code: 415
```

Nothing about this error in API document.

```
from watson_developer_cloud import AlchemyLanguageV1
alchemy_language = AlchemyLanguageV1(url="https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api",
          username="xxx",
          password="xxx")
print(json.dumps(alchemy_language.sentiment(text="hehe")))
```

Comment: do u get error when constucting AlchemyLanguageV1 object or when calling the sentiment() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because AlchemyLanguageV1 is no longer supported. IBM has integrated this component to Watson Natural Language Understanding. Refer docs for Watson Natural Language Understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Please look carefully on the [sample code](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemy-language/api/v1/?python#sentiment). First of all, it constructs an AlchemyLanguageV1 object using an API key, not login and password, maybe that is the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the end of request with Alchemy Language `()` and add a `,`, after this add the `indent` parameter.

I thought this parameter is required because isn't set the datatype inside the request (Example `application/json`, etc)...

And **all request** inside the documentation has the parameter `indent=2`.

I'm not sure about that, probably someone who work at IBM will confirm.

**Check this example:**

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import AlchemyLanguageV1

alchemy_language = AlchemyLanguageV1(api_key='API_KEY')
print(json.dumps(
  alchemy_language.sentiment(
    text='hehe'),
  indent=2))
```

I made this conclusion by testing with the documentation link: [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemy-language/api/v1/#sentiment)